# setUp() not being called in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

For some reason, the setUp() method of my test class is not being called before my test method.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class BlockchainAuctionTest {
    private BlockchainAuction auction;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    auction = new BlockchainAuction();
    System.out.println("setUp");
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    System.out.println("tearDown");
}

@Test
void testOneBid() {
    Bid bid = new Bid("Bitcoin", "Devon", 1.0);
    assertTrue(auction.recordNewBid(bid), "first bid should be added without error");
}
}
```

Specifically, I am getting a null pointer exception on the line that says

`assertTrue(auction.recordNewBid(bid), "first bid should be added without error");`

because auction has not been initialized. I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

You're using a JUnit 5 `@Test` but JUnit 4 `@Before`/`@After`.

You need to use `@BeforeEach`/`@AfterEach` from `org.junit.jupiter`.

Answer (score 3):

From what it looks like, you can try changing the import from

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

to

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, For me this is how it worked.
I have used:

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;`

And it worked. I have also used

`import org.junit.Before; 
import org.junit.Test;`

It also worked. Any other combination doesn't worked for me.